# React Hook Form Different Validations based on the button clicked

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a React hook form and user can click on two different types of submit actions, both of which require different validations for the the fields, i also need to do have validations on change.

Not able to figure out since the only place i can see is to keep validation schema is in useForm

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to explain your question